# Is there a similar process like hysteresis for dielectrics/dipoles?

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, dipole

Hysteresis is shown in the following image from hyperphysics:
[image]

Does a similar curve exists for dipoles? For example given a dielectric medium inside a capacitor, the electric field will induce a dipole in the dielectric medium. This is similar to a ferromagnet where a magnetic field gets induced. The difference is that the dielectric is completely neutral (I believe) at the atomic scale. But you could imagine using a dielectric with molecules that have a significant dipole moment.

Answer (score 1):

[**Ferroelectricity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity) is a similar phenomenon, characterized by existence of permanent electric polarization due to the dipole moments aligning in a specific direction.

In this sense one could note the parallel termonology:

- Ferromagnetics/Ferroelectrics (permanent magnetic/electric polarization)
- Paramagnetics/paralelectrics (although paraelectrics is a relatively rare term) - small amplification of the external field
- Diamagnetics/dielectrics - attenuation/dicreasing of the external field

Note also that Ferroelectricity is easily neutralized under normal conditions, due to the charged dust particles condensing on the material, which is why it is less used then ferromagnetism (ubiquitous in modern electronics).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and this is an important effect in electronics. Capacitors aren't ideally supposed to dissipate energy, but they do, and dielectric hysteresis is a common mechanism. It's especially important in the ubiquitous ceramic capacitors.

Dielectric hysteresis can also cause unwanted "memory" in a circuit. The video filters for ACIS on [NASA's Chandra X-ray Observatory](https://chandra.harvard.edu/) are largely copied from the ones I designed for the low-cost HETE-1 mission. For HETE, I chose Panasonic-branded integration capacitors with excellent (low) hysteresis specs. But Chandra had a much higher budget, and the engineers adapting my design insisted on substituting expensive "high reliability" capacitors. These came with lots of paper, but no hysteresis spec. In testing, the results were abominable: the amplitude of a given pixel showed a strong dependence on the amplitude of the preceding pixel. After much catalog perusal I was able to find capacitors that would do the job and satisfy the engineers. They didn't fit the board footprint, but that's what clever, skilled technicians are for ツ

Comment: That is interesting thank you for your answer